# Jquery Modal Popup window in Salesforce is vanishing after it shows for 2 seconds

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visualforce-component, jquery

I have a button, onclick of that i want to display the modal pop up window.
Here's what i have done- Window is displayed for 2 seconds and then it vanishes! what might be the problem?

```
  <script>
             $j=jQuery.noConflict();

              $j(document).ready(function() {

                 $j('input[id$=loginbtn]').click(function(event) {

                    $j('#login').dialog({autoOpen: shallIOpen(), 
                            title: 'Login:',
                             resizable: false, width: 600,height: 200,
                             autoResize: true, modal: true,draggable: true,
                            buttons: [ { text: "Ok", click: function() { $j( this).dialog( "close" ); }} ] })  
         });
    });

         function shallIOpen(){
             if({!logindisplay}){
                  return true;
             }
             else{
                 return false;
             }
         }
```

```
<body>
         <apex:form >
         <apex:commandButton value="Click Here to Login" id="loginbtn"  action="{!login}"/>
         </apex:form>
</body>
```

logindisplay is a boolean declared in the controller

```
public boolean logindisplay{get;set;}
//constructor
public jPopUpController(){
    logindisplay=true;
}
//method called when clicked on the button
public void login(){
    logindisplay=true;

}
```

Where have i gone wrong? Pop is appearing for only 2 secods and it is disappearing! when i clicked on the button.

Comment: Perhaps the underlying button submit is causing this; adding event.preventDefault() to your click function should stop that.

Comment: @KeithC Don't forget to promote this comment to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the underlying button submit is causing this; adding event.preventDefault() to your click function should stop that.

Comment: Adding event.preventDefault() effect the action attribute of the <apex:commandButton action={!loginmethod} value="Click to Login" />. Any idea of an alternative method so that method defined in the controller is called after i click the command button?

Comment: @AkashNidhiPS I would assume that you want the controller method called when your dialog OK is clicked? You can use apex:actionFunction for that - see e.g. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm.

Comment: Yea i need to call <apex:actionfuntion> using onClick attribute. And need to call a method from action function. Thanks for the reply :)