# Jquery modal popup escaping

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have a vf page in which the Javascript function `OpenRegistrationPage1` is called through .Now in that function the confirmation box is being called..The box is displayed but it is vanishing immedialty and the page is reloading again.I have even gone through this [Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/jquery-modal-popup-window-in-salesforce-is-vanishing-after-it-shows-for-2-second)..But that seems different.I am unable to understand what is going wrong here..

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="PolicyHolderDetails" id="pg" docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="true">
<apex:slds />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
var flag=0;
var Insurance;

function OpenRegistrationPage1(){   

    $( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "New User": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "Existing User": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  } );
Insurance=document.getElementById('{!$Component.pg.f.HI}').innerHTML;
}
function OpenRegistrationPage2(){ 
flag++;
 Insurance=document.getElementById('{!$Component.pg.f.HOI}').innerHTML;
}
function OpenRegistrationPage3(){   
flag++;
Insurance=document.getElementById('{!$Component.pg.f.LI}').innerHTML;
}
function OpenRegistrationPage4(){   
flag++;
Insurance=document.getElementById('{!$Component.pg.f.AI}').innerHTML;
}


</script>
<apex:form id="f" >
<center><h1 style="font-size:30px;">Get Insured with our Policies</h1></center>
<apex:image height="40%" width="3%" url="{!$Resource.HandSymbol}"/>
 <apex:commandLink value="Health Insurance" style="font-size:15px" onclick="OpenRegistrationPage1()" id="HI"/><br/>
 <apex:image height="40%" width="3%" url="{!$Resource.HandSymbol}"/>
    <apex:commandLink value="Home Insurance" style="font-size:15px" onclick="OpenRegistrationPage2()" id="HOI"/><br/>
 <apex:image height="40%" width="3%" url="{!$Resource.HandSymbol}"/>
      <apex:commandLink value="Life Insurance" style="font-size:15px" onclick="OpenRegistrationPage3()" id="LI"/><br/>
     <apex:image height="40%" width="3%" url="{!$Resource.HandSymbol}"/>
        <apex:commandLink value="Automobile Insurance" style="font-size:15px" onclick="OpenRegistrationPage4()" id="AI"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="PassValues" action="{!CheckInsurance}" rerender="none">
        <apex:param name="Param1" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>




    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Are you a new User Or Existing User??">
  <!--<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>Are you a new User or Existing User?</p>-->
</div> 
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You should probably update your post to include what you have tried to correct the behavior, any debugging? what part isint working according to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the command link it submits the form and (without a rerender) rerenders the entire page thus causing your dialog to be hidden again.

**Add a rerender**

```
     <apex:commandLink value="Health Insurance" style="font-size:15px" 
        onclick="OpenRegistrationPage1()" rerender="nothing" id="HI"/><br/>
```

You should also update to the latest version of jQuery and use HTTPS on all your references.

- You are also missing the https:// on the first reference. Relative URLs to code.jquery.com will not work since the page is not hosted on code.jquery.com

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
       href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
  ```